# Render a button like a couple of spans in CSS

Tags: html, css, button

I want to render a couple of submit buttons (they stands in the center of a paragraph, right under a form) exactly as in this html code:

```css
span {
  background-color: #cbaa5c;
  padding: 4px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<p style="text-align:center;">
  <span>
    <span style="border-right-width:2px; border-right-style:solid; border-right-color:#ffffff;">
      Login
    </span>
    <span>
      >
    </span>
  </span>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <span>
    <span class='butleftspan' style="border-right-width:2px; border-right-style:solid; border-right-color:#ffffff;">
      Register
    </span>
    <span>
      >
    </span>
  </span>
</p>
```

The code above generate these two spans that are the result I aim to achieve:

[image: HERE IS THE PICTURE OF THE RESULT THAT I'D WANT TO REACH!]

This is exactly how I want that the two working buttons (and not only two spans) appear.

I tried to obtain the same result as in the picture and code above defining buttons,tables inside of buttons, spans an everything possible in the world, but I can't achieve my purpose. Any help will be super-appreciate! Thanks in advance!

In simple terms I'd want to have a Login and a register button that appears exactly as in the picture (that i obtained from the HTML code above).

Comment: didn't got what you want?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please post images of the desired results, because I don't really get what you are after either

Comment: I uploaded the picture: follow the link in the post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far I understand from your question you want the same result but using a [`button`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) tag, in that case you can use `::after` to insert the ">" symbol and achieve with CSS this:

```css
p {
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  background: #cbaa5c;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  line-height: 2;
  padding: 0 8px;
}

button:after {
  content: ">";
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 8px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <button>LOGIN</button>
  <button>REGISTER</button>
</p>
```